# Solve the following equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need help to solve the following equation.

$13x=4x^2$

My attempt:

$13x=4x^2$

$4x^2-13x=0$

$\frac{4x^2-13x}{4}=0$

$x^2-\frac{13x}{4}+0=0$

$x=-\frac{-13}{2} \begin{matrix} + \\ - \end{matrix} \sqrt{(\frac{-13}{2})^2}$

this results to $x1 = 8.125$ $x2 = -4.875$

The correct result is $x1 = 0$ $x2 = 3.25$

Where did I go wrong with this?

Thanks!!

Comment: Can you divide both sides by x so that $13=4x$ and then x=13/4?

Comment: Are you sure you require the differential equations tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nice attempt but you have over complicated things for yourself there!

Let me carry on for from $4x^2-13x=0$

I know that maybe plugging into the quadratic formula may be the first instinct, but we can simply this by factorizing out an $x$.

$4x^2-13x=4x \times x-13x=x(4x-13)$

So here we get that $x=0$ is a solution which will be your $x_1$.  All that is left to solve is the other bracket $(4x-13)=0$ for your $x_2$.  I think you should get the answer you are looking for!

Answer (score 1):

I will go ahead and add this as an answer since it confirms your posted solutions.

$13x=4x^2$

divide both sides by x so that you have

$13=4x$

solve for $x=13/4$ which equals 3.25.

And of course, 0 exists as the trivial solution.

Answer (score 0):

First you see that $x = 0$ is a solution, because on both sides there are no additional numbers or other factors. Then you assume that x $does not$ equal $0$ to search for more solutions. Then you can just divide by x (this is allowed because x is in this case not 0), which leads to:

$$4x = 13$$

Then you obtain the second solution.

Answer (score 0):

$13x=x^2$

If $x\neq 0$ we can divide both sides by $x$ to obtain:

$\frac{13x}{x}=\frac{4x^2}{x}\Rightarrow 13=4x$

Then we divide both sides by $4$ to obtain:

$x = \frac{13}{4}$.